# How do i modify a UILabel's properties when my MyViewController is unarchived from a nib?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I am currently creating my first app for a personal project and I'm having trouble modifying a UILabel's properties when MyViewController is loaded.

From other tutorials, I see that when the nib for my app is unarchived, the initWithCoder app is called:

```
@synthesize tipText; //references the UILabel i created in my nib file

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {

    if (self = [super initWithCoder:coder]) {
        self.tipText.layer.cornerRadius = 8; //the UILabel property i wish to modify
    }

    return self;
}
```

However, when the above code runs, the tipText is not bound to any memory yet.

Where should i place my `self.tipText.layer.cornerRadius` code such that `tipText` is initialized and before the UILabel is displayed in my UI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to do this in -[UIViewController viewDidLoad]

Comment: This worked! An example of viewDidLoad can be seen here in the "Implementing viewDidLoad" section:

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Articles/02_RootViewController.html

Answer (score 1):

you should implement the following method

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
```

and make changes there.  This method is called on objects after they are unfrozen from a nib file.